# ejabberd Mnesia database backup

Tags: backup, archive, ejabberd, mnesia, muc

Does making an ejabberd binary backup of mnesia database from the admin panel will also back up archived messages stored in MUC archive and private chats archive? If not, how to back up archived messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ejabberd Mnesia backup backups all the data stored in Mnesia, so if your archive are in Mnesia they will be backuped as well.

However, like always with backup, you must test the process from backup to restore to validate that it works as expected and matches your needs.